# Is there a #$P$-complete counting problem such that every (valid) instance of its decision version is a Yes-instance?

Tags: decision-problem, turing-completeness, counting

I want to know whether there is a decision problem, written *EasyProblem*, satisfying the follow property:

- For every valid instance $x$, $x$ is a Yes-instance for *EasyProblem* (if we construct *EasyProblem* as a nature problem). Formally speaking, maybe we can define *EasyProblem* as a language $L \in \mathrm{DTIME}(n)$ or even $L \in \mathrm{DTIME}(1)$.
- The counting version #*EasyProblem* is in #$P$-complete.

Really what I'm asking is: can we construct a very easy decision problem, but its counting version is too hard? Or can we construct a very hard counting poblem, but its decision version is too easy?

Answer (score 1):

An example of a such problem in $\mathrm{DTIME}(n)$ is DNF satisfiability [1]. Its counting version is #P-complete [2], but its decision version can be solved by simply checking if there is a conjunction that is satisfiable.

For $\mathrm{DTIME}(1)$ I think the answer is that there are no such problems because we can iterate over all computation paths in $O(1)$ so counting is easy.

Note that in general, disallowing instances with answer 0 does not change the #P-completeness of any problem whose decision version is in P because we can check this case in polynomial time.

[1] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form

[2] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete

Comment: If we disallow the instance with answer 0, then we can construct an algorithm that returns Yes in $O(1)$ time (since we can encode all the invalid input to as a string). How to understand the second paragraph in your answer? It make sense, but there is a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good point. I think the contradiction arises from non-rigorous definitions. In particular, I think the definition that there are Yes-instances, No-instances, and invalid instances is incompatible with the standard definitions of #P-completeness. For the standard definitions there are only Yes-instances and No-instances (invalid instances are No-instances).

Comment: Let me give an example, suppose that $L = \{ y \vee \varphi \mid \varphi \text{ is a DNF with varibles } x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \}$. Since #DNF is #$\mathrm{P}$-complete, so is $L$. But $L \in \mathrm{DTIME}(1)$ right? Otherwise, there is not a $\mathrm{DTIME}(1)$ language anymore.

Comment: You need to use at least $\Theta(n)$ computation to check if the input is a valid representation of DNF (note that inputs are binary strings, not arbitrary data). Yeah I guess there is not many interesting languages in DTIME(1).

Comment: I think I have got the answer that I want. That is there do exist a decision problem in $\mathrm{DTIME}(1)$, but the counting version is complete in #$\mathrm{P}$. (Thanks to your answer,) $L = \{ y \vee \varphi \mid \varphi \text{ is a DNF with variables }x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \}$.

Comment: First of all, I do not think we need to consider the procedure which is used to check the valid representation of an instance, in general, because we always assume that there is an efficient bijection between valid inputs and $\Sigma^*$. Second, it is obvious that $L$ can be solved in $O(1)$ time, and it is not necessary to distinguish the time complexity of a natural problem and its formal version.

Comment: Finally, for a $\mathrm{DTIME}(1)$ problem $P$, the counting version #$P$ can not be solved in $O(1)$ time in general, we cannot gurantee the number of the witnesses of an instance is bounded. Although, we have that if the answer is yes, then every computation path accepts, and there exists a $O(1)$ depth computation path halts. But we cannot gurantee the depth of all the computstion path is $O(1)$.

Comment: "we always assume that there is an efficient bijection between valid inputs and $\Sigma^*$" -- I think this is wrong, especially in our context where we do non-standard things with defining what inputs are valid and what are not.